# Android packaging error

Tags: java, android

When I compile my Android Project I always get this Error:

> Error generating final archive: duplicate entry: about.html

But I can't find any about.html in my Project.
Does anyone know how to solve the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it at all possible that you have an about.xml that is duplicated? Or maybe accidentally named about.html somewhere?

Or are you using any external jars? maybe there is in issue in one of those?

Comment: I am using external jars. But how can I find out if it is in there and remove it?

Comment: I dont have Eclipse in front of me right now, but try right-clicking on your project and go to references. Try fiddling with the options there.

Comment: I didn't find anything out with Eclipse, but I could open them in PeaZip. There where about.htmls in there. But how can I remove them?

Comment: I could remove them in PeaZip. (How silly from me not to try that instanltly) but the error is still there.

Comment: I can try to look at some stuff tonight when I get home(unless its solved sooner). Would you mind telling me the external jar's name so I can try it out(unless of course its proprietary :)?

Comment: The jars are the servlet-api-3.0.jar, jetty-server-8.0.0.M1.jar and jetty-util-8.0.0.M1.jar of the Jetty http server (http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/8.0.0.M1/dist/jetty-distribution-8.0.0.M1.zip). Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Well I tried looking into it, but I really couldnt figure anything out. The only thing I can recommend is right-clicking on your project, going to Properties, and messing with the settings there. Also, you *MAY* need to add something to your manifest if your using certain jars.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if multiple referenced jars contain the same resources (i.e. about.html). I guess you are using jars from eclipse, since its release train requires every released jar to have an about.html contained.

Would be nice, if the android compiler could be told to ignore certain duplications, after all it seems to does so with Manifest.MF files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help or not, but have you tried the clean up function for your android project? Just curious if that would help this problem. If you right click on your project and go to android tools there is an option to clean up. See if that does anything.

Let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: If you meant the "Fix Project Properties" button: No, nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah that is what i meant. Sorry to hear that did not help.